# Collection Repeat without full Ionic Bundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would love to be able to use Ionic's collect-repeat directive, however the entire Ionic bundle is not suitable for the solution I am developing.

I am trying to strip the code I need to implement it in a web app, however it's looking like an awful lot of code to get one directive working.

Has anyone come across a similar solution without using Ionic or has successfully implemented collect-repeat from Ionic without using the entire bundle?

Any advice would be great!

Thanks

Comment: I found [this](http://loring-dodge.azurewebsites.net/re-creating-collection-repeat-an-improved-ng-repeat-for-large-sets/), but I have not tried to implement it myself. May be worth a look.